# How to limit Fibonacci Sequence in an array under a Number Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a Fibonacci Sequence javascript solution. I was able to push out a Fibonacci Sequence array. However, this solution add an extra number in the array that is more than the limited number.

For example, if I want all the numbers in the array to be under 10, then the array should be [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]. However, with my solution, it still output the extra "13" in the array.

```js
function fib(num) {
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var fibarray = [0, 1];

while(y < num) {
    y += x;
    x = y - x;
    fibarray.push(y);
}

return fibarray;
}
console.log(fib(10));
```

I don't understand why it output "13" when it shouldn't work as "13" is more than "10". Please help me fix this solution.

Comment: You increment `y` **after** `while` ensured that it was within range,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is happening because you are computing next y, pushing it to array and then checking if y is less than num or not but by then you have already added y to fibarray. Solution would be to check if y is less than num and then push it to fibarray and then compute next y and while condition is checked all over again.

```js
function fib(num) {
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var fibarray = [0];

while(y < num) {
    fibarray.push(y);
    y += x;
    x = y - x;
}

return fibarray;
}
console.log(fib(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

...Or you can check that `y+x < 10` not just `y < 10`

```js
function fib(num) {
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var fibarray = [0, 1];

while(y+x < num) {
    y += x;
    x = y - x;
    fibarray.push(y);
}

return fibarray;
}
console.log(fib(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

put this if statement within while loop to check that new y is less than num

```js
function fib(num) {
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var fibarray = [0, 1];

while(y < num) {
    y += x;
    x = y - x;
    if(y<num){
    fibarray.push(y);
    }
}

return fibarray;
}
console.log(fib(10));
```

Comment: I would avoid using the same condition two times and use instead Dij's or my solution.

Comment: @Stephan, why should I avoid using the same condition two times? What's Dij's?

Comment: for me there is no security reasons to avoid that and also Dij's idea is a very good idea with minimum code

Comment: That was only an aesthetic notice, it is (not only computationally) more complex than necessary. Even though that is not relevant for such a small snippet, I personally prefer solutions which are easier to understand and maintain. With Dij's solution I meant the oldest answer to this question.

Comment: Stephan you are right if I have the choice I will prefer Dij and Will suggestion in programming there is a word always used "Don't repeat yourself" but it is also a working code with no error

Answer (score 0):

It adds 13 because you modify `y` after comparing to `num`.
A solution would be:

```
function fib(num) {
  var x = 0;
  var y = 1;
  var fibarray = [0, 1];

  while(true) {
    y += x;
    x = y - x;
    if(y>num) return fibarray;
    fibarray.push(y);
  }
}
```

Comment: changing to "because you modify `y` after comparing to `num`"

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, the reason for this is that "while(y < num)" lopps until you encounter a number greater than 10. As "fibarray.push(y);" is at the end of your loop, this means that when you get 8, it goes back into the loop once more. You don't have anything stopping it from pushing the 13 at that time.

Two options you have are to either include an if statement before the push statement (but after "x = y - x;") that says to exit the loop (e.g. "if(y >= 10){break;}"), or you can set the loop to be for numbers less than 8.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fib(num) {
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var fibarray = [0,1];

while(y < num) {
    y += x;
    x = y - x;
    if(num < y) {
   return fibarray;
     }
   fibarray.push(y);
}


}
console.log(fib(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [0, 1];
var limit = 33;

while (arr[arr.length - 1] + arr[arr.length - 2] <= limit) {
    arr[arr.length] = arr[arr.length - 1] + arr[arr.length - 2];
}
console.log(arr.join(", "));
```

Comment: It would help learners if you added some explanation. Code only answers are not often helpful.